# How to make use of angle sum and difference identities to find the value of sine and cosine?

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers, pi

> Calculate: $\cos\left({5\pi\over12}\right)$ and $\cos\left({\pi\over12}\right)$

What is the easiest way to find $\cos\left({5\pi\over12}\right)$ and $\cos\left({\pi\over12}\right)$ (without a calculator)? If I know that $\frac{5\pi }{12}=\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{\pi }{6}$ and $\frac{\pi }{12}=\frac{\pi }{3}-\frac{\pi }{4}$, then I can apply [angle sum and difference identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities). But how do I know $\frac{5\pi }{12}= \frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{\pi }{6}$ and $\frac{\pi }{12}= \frac{\pi }{3}-\frac{\pi }{4}$ in the first place. I know $ \frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{\pi }{6} = \frac{5\pi }{12}$ and $ \frac{\pi }{3}-\frac{\pi }{4}=\frac{\pi }{12}$ but I can't go the other way round.

I gave $\frac{5\pi}{12}$ and $\frac{\pi}{12}$ as an example, I want the general solution for any value in pi rational form $\frac{\pi p}{q}$.

Comment: My approach to such problems is to consider known values as building blocks, and then use trial and error to express the unknown values in terms of the known values.  For example, the trig functions of the following special angles are generally known: $\{0, \pi/6, \pi/4, \pi/3, \pi/2\}.$  Also, I know of three separate derivations (Geometry, Real Analysis, Complex Analysis) for $(\pi/10)$, so that gets added to the list.  Also, [half-angle formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) gives you $(\pi/12)$. ...see next comment

Comment: Further, [angle-sum formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) then gives you (for example) $(5\pi/12).$  Therefore, the general procedure is to consider known values/formulas as building blocks, and try to attack the unknown values with your building blocks.

Comment: @user2661923 I am not able find the value of $(\pi/10)$ using the identities. Can you please share the derivations you know? Also, you should convert your comments to an answer. Thank you!

Comment: I am not allowed to *answer* your question, because you haven't really *shown* work, in accordance with [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and my interactions with the mathSE *answer police* are distasteful to me.  Using trig identities, you should be able to derive $\sin(5x) = 16\sin^5(x) - 20\sin^3(x) + 5\sin(x).$  Lettting $y = \sin(2\pi/5) = \cos(\pi/10)$, noting that (therefore) $y > 0$ and also noting that $y$ must be a root of $[y(16y^4 - 20y^2 + 5)] = 0,~$ you have a routinely solvable quadratic equation in $(y^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find the values of $\displaystyle\cos\frac{5\pi}{12}$ and $\displaystyle\cos\frac{\pi}{12}$.

Recall the sum to product formulae below:
$$\begin{align}\cos A+\cos B&=2\cos\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}\\
\cos A-\cos B&=-2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2}\\\end{align}.$$
In our case, let $A=5\pi/12$ and $B=\pi/12$. Then we find that
$$\begin{align}\cos\frac{5\pi}{12}+\cos\frac{\pi}{12}&=2\cos\frac{\frac{5\pi}{12}+\frac{\pi}{12}}{2}\cos\frac{\frac{5\pi}{12}-\frac{\pi}{12}}{2}=2\cos\frac{\pi}{4}\cos\frac{\pi}{6}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt6}{2}\tag{1}\\
\cos\frac{5\pi}{12}-\cos\frac{\pi}{12}&=-2\sin\frac{\frac{5\pi}{12}+\frac{\pi}{12}}{2}\sin\frac{\frac{5\pi}{12}-\frac{\pi}{12}}{2}=-2\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\sin\frac{\pi}{6}\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\tag{2}.\end{align}$$
Adding equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ together and dividing by $2$, we find that
$$\cos\frac{5\pi}{12}=\frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4}$$
and subtracting equation $(2)$ from equation $(1)$ and dividing by $2$ gives
$$\cos\frac{\pi}{12}=\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4}.$$

---

However, this method is not always guaranteed to work, for the simple reason that $\cos x\pi$ does not always have a closed form for  rational $x$.

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

1 equation and 2 unknows is, generally, an overdetermined system.

In this case, pick any solution for $\dfrac{5\pi}{12} = \dfrac{p_1\pi}{q_1} + \dfrac{p_2\pi}{q_2}$, and sum $\pm \dfrac{p_3\pi}{q_3}$ in a smart way

$$\dfrac{5\pi}{12} = \left( \dfrac{p_1\pi}{q_1} +  \dfrac{p_3\pi}{q_3} \right) + \left( \dfrac{p_2\pi}{q_2} -  \dfrac{p_3\pi}{q_3} \right)$$

$$\dfrac{5\pi}{12} = \dfrac{\pi}{6} + \dfrac{\pi}{4} = \dfrac{\pi}{3} + \dfrac{\pi}{12} = \dfrac{3\pi}{10} + \dfrac{7\pi}{60} = \dots $$

Answer (score 0):

We know that

$$\begin{align}
\cos{\pi\over 4}&=\sin{\pi\over 4}={\sqrt{2}\over 2}\\
\cos{\pi\over 6}&=\sin{\pi\over 3}={\sqrt{3}\over 2}\\
\cos{\pi\over 3}&=\sin{\pi\over 6}={1\over 2}\\
\cos(x+y)&=\cos{x}\cos{y}-\sin{x}\sin{y}\\
\cos(x-y)&=\cos{x}\cos{y}+\sin{x}\sin{y}\\
\sin(x+y)&=\sin{x}\cos{y}+\cos{x}\sin{y}\\
\cos(x-y)&=\sin{x}\cos{y}-\cos{x}\sin{y}\\
\end{align}$$

With the above you should be done.

Answer (score 0):

After practicing a lot of problems in trigonometry, I realized that I need to know the values of sine and cosine only at $\{ \pi/6, \pi/4, \pi/3\}$, and the double angle, half angle and sum and difference identities. @marwalix et al. answered the same.

By applying the double angle formula (i.e. $\sin \left( 2\theta \right) =2\sin \theta \cos \theta$), I found the value of $\{\pi/5, 2\pi/5\}$:

$$\dfrac{\pi }{5}=2\cdot \dfrac{\pi }{10}$$
$$\dfrac{2\pi }{5}=2\cdot \dfrac{\pi }{5}$$

By applying the half angle formula (i.e. $\sin \dfrac{\theta }{2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos \theta }{2}}$, $\cos \dfrac{\theta }{2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos \theta }{2}}$), I found the value of $\{ \pi/12, \pi/8\}$:

$$\dfrac{\pi }{12}=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{\pi }{6}$$
$$\dfrac{\pi }{8}=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{\pi }{4}$$

And finally, by applying $\sin(\alpha \pm \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta \pm \cos \alpha \sin \beta$, and $\cos(\alpha \pm \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta \mp \sin \alpha \sin \beta$, I found the value of $\{ \pi/12, 3\pi/10, 3\pi/8, 5\pi/12\}$:

$$\dfrac{\pi }{12}=\dfrac{\pi }{3}-\dfrac{\pi }{4}=\dfrac{\pi }{4}-\dfrac{\pi }{6}$$
$$\dfrac{3\pi }{10}= \dfrac{\pi }{10}+\dfrac{\pi }{5}=\dfrac{2\pi }{5}-\dfrac{\pi }{10}$$
$$\dfrac{3\pi }{8}=\dfrac{\pi }{4}+\dfrac{\pi }{8}, \dfrac{5\pi }{12}=\dfrac{\pi }{4}+\dfrac{\pi }{6}$$

The values that I found at $\{0, \pi/12, \pi/10, \pi/6, \pi/5, \pi/4, 3\pi/10, \pi/3, 3\pi/8, 2\pi/5, 5\pi/12, \pi/10\}$ are as follows:
[image: rendered image]

Comment: Nice table, did you make it? How?